# Hide symbol for external link if the link is empty

Tags: hyperlink, href

I am creating a Resume and I am using a Latex template for it.There is a specific command defined for projects which has two parameters: name of the project and url of the project. It then prints the name of the project in big bold letters and creates a symbol for external link to the project. The code is as follows:

```
% Project command
\newcommand{\Project}[2]{
\runsubsection{%
\href{#2}{\uppercase{#1} \,\faExternalLink}
}
\hfill
}
```

My problem is that for some of my project, I don't have an external link to them (no second parameter). However, if I leave the second parameter empty, it still creates the symbol for external link, just you cannot click on the symbol, but the symbol still appears in the final document. Is there any way to remove the symbol for external link if the second parameter of  `\Project` command is left empty?

Comment: It is a lot easier to make the first argument optional.  Then just check for the default value (e.g.\empty or a quark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to make the external link an optional argument:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Project}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% no external link
    \runsubsection{\uppercase{#2}}%
  }{% external link
    \runsubsection{\href{#1}{\uppercase{#2} \faExternalLink}}%
  }%
}
```

to be called as

```
\Project{Something with no link}
```

or

```
\Project[http://example.com]{Something with a link}
```

If you have a release of LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01 you need also `\usepackage{xparse}`.

However, this would produce several warnings, because `\uppercase` is not really allowed in `\href`. Better code follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\runsubsection}{\subsection} % just for the test

\NewDocumentCommand{\Project}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% no external link
    \runsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}}%
  }{% external link
    \runsubsection{\href{#1}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#2}}{#2}\texorpdfstring{ \faLink}{}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\Project{Something with no link}

\Project[http://example.com]{Something with a link}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I used `\faLink` because `\faExternalLink` requires the Pro version of `fontawesome5`.

You could also use an expandable version of `\MakeUppercase`, that would also uppercase the bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\runsubsection}{\subsection} % just for the test

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \xMakeUppercase \text_uppercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\Project}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% no external link
    \runsubsection{\xMakeUppercase{#2}}%
  }{% external link
    \runsubsection{\href{#1}{\xMakeUppercase{#2}\texorpdfstring{ \faLink}{}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\Project{Something with no link}

\Project[http://example.com]{Something with a link}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, it is working, thanks! Can I ask what does this `{om}` behind `\NewDocumentCommand{\Project}` stand for, why `om`?

Comment: @doremi `o` stands for an optional argument with no default value (its presence can be tested with `\IfNoValueTF`) and `m` stands for a mandatory argument.